# How to place a date in a tooltip when only part of axis ticks with dates are shown? Using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart with the dates along the x-axis. I define the x-axis this way:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(xScale)
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(d3.time.months, 1)
          .tickSize(0)
          .tickFormat(RU.timeFormat("%b %Y"));
```

After that I pick the dates from the axis texts and put them in tooltips. This way:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        var tickDate = d3.select(d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i]).data()[0];
        var formatDate = RU.timeFormat("%B %Y");
        var tooltipDate = formatDate(tickDate);
```

And everything is ok with this approach until I'm changing the frequency of the ticks with the dates in this row:

```
.ticks(d3.time.months, 2)
```

After that the part of tooltips disappears. How can I fix this mistake?
My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/cLb1nxwj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in mouseover where you try to bind the data with the dates: 
`var tickDate = d3.select(d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i]).data()[0];`
and then try to get the correct date

```
// here d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i] fails and returns undefined
// because i is out of range since there are more data than months
var tickDate = d3.select(d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0][i]).data()[0];
var formatDate = RU.timeFormat("%B %Y");
// so formatDate fails when trying to format an empty value
var tooltipDate = formatDate(tickDate);
```

You could try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/b03prLm8/5/

Where:

```
    // you get your dates with length 10
    var dates = d3.selectAll(".axis .tick text")[0];

    // Since it is two values per date - with one exception see below
    // check if the current value's modulo with two (the ticks freq.) is zero
    // if not, use ceil to get the correct bin/ date the value belongs
    // e.g. if i is 9, then 9/2=4.5 becomes 4, so 9 belongs to the 4th date
    // and so on...
    var index = (i % 2 == 0)
                        ? i/2
                        : Math.ceil(i/ 2);

    if(index > 0) index -= 1; // because the first bar is not within the dates range
    // then go on as usual
    var tickDate = d3.select(dates[index]).data()[0];
    var formatDate = RU.timeFormat("%B %Y");
    var tooltipDate = formatDate(tickDate);
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!